# how to take postgres server backup skipping some of databases?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have PostgreSQL server version 9.5. Contains 20 Databases.

I want take server backup skipping of some 10 databases.

Am using pg_dumpall, but it was taking full server backup.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `pg_dumpall`, just use `pg_dump` and specify which databases you want to dump.  One possible way to do it is:

```sh
for db in <space-separated list of database names>
do
  pg_dump -U <user> -h <host> ${db} > ${db}.dmp
done
```